# Write to SD card storage on Android, does not create file at all. Why?

Tags: android, database

I have been experimenting with writing to **sdcard storage** in my Android application (Target API 11)

I have been successful in creating the Directory in the following code called "BPAExp_data" but it does not create a new file at all. I'm stumped as to why since it does not show up in the logcat!!.

Here is my onCreate() method

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_logger);
    String data = "asdfghjkl.."

    //The filename of the log file
    filename = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Filename");

    //Save Test data button
    Button saveData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveDataButton);
    saveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Save Data in file and go back to home screen
        addtoKeyLogFile(data);              

        //Make intent for the Main Activity screen
        Intent main_intent = new Intent(TextLogger.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main_intent);
        }
    });
```

This is my method called addKeyLogFile()

```
    public void addtoKeyLogFile(String data){       
    FileOutputStream f = null;
    File data_file;
    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/BPAExp_data");
        dir.mkdirs();
        data_file = new File(dir, filename);
        f = new FileOutputStream(data_file);
        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!data_file.exists()) {
            data_file.createNewFile();
            Toast.makeText(TextLogger.this, "File GOT CREATED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] dataInBytes = data.getBytes();

        f.write(dataInBytes);
        f.flush();
        f.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TextLogger onCreate: ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TextLogger onCreate: ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (f != null) {
                f.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have Located that the problem lies in or near the

```
    f = new FileOutputStream(data_file);
```

because when I put a  toast message after that it is never executed BUT if I put a toast before it, it is executed!  Also the intent after that works perfectly fine!
But I do NOT understand, why is it not working?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File has multiple constructors. One take as parameters a File and  String:

```
File dir = new File (sdCard , "BPAExp_data");
dir.mkdirs();
data_file = new File(dir, filename);
```

What's the value of filename ?

remove those lines:

```
   if (!data_file.exists()) {
          data_file.createNewFile();
          Toast.makeText(TextLogger.this, "File GOT CREATED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

File will be created when you stop writing the file.

```
 f.close();
```

you call it twice. Leave it only inside the finally block

All in all, are you sure  that you have something to write?

```
byte[] dataInBytes = data.getBytes();
```

is the length of `dataInBytes > 0` ?

Comment: `I have been successful in creating the Directory in the following code called "BPAExp_data" but it does not create a new file at all.`

Comment: If a directory can be created on the external storage, then permissions are not the problem.  You might try logging the result of each file operation, particularly the absolute path and the resulting objects to make sure they are non-null.  Also make sure your exception handling code will result in log messages rather than silently consume the exceptions.

Comment: I have the filename stored in a String variable (not a prob!) 

Yes, dataInBytes is not zero! I checkeed it once again!
This still did not solve my problem!

Comment: Please try and help again, I think there is something wronf after the FileOutputStream statement!

Comment: All right I got the BUG ! After the changes you suggested, my filename  also contained chars like "**:**" and "**/**" which are not allowed in filenames! Hence it was not creating the file at all!